# How can I ensure a null is assigned to a variable when using MAX in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, null

I have another question dealing with Nulls in Oracle.

I have a small table that is used as a session table. Each row is a specific session.
If a session is finished successfully the final column indicates a version number or null if the session is dropped.

This column can be null and I want to select either the max version number or null into a sessionNumber variable .
This was the origanal I had set up

```
SELECT MAX (VerNumber) INTO sessionNumber
FROM Table_A
WHERE sessionDate = -- some date
AND VerNumber IS NOT NULL;
```

this returns one row when the col is null

I tried using NVL like this

```
SELECT NVL(MAX (VerNumber),NULL) INTO sessionNumber
FROM Table_A
WHERE sessionDate = -- some date
AND VerNumber IS NOT NULL;
```

To hopefully clear up confusion, the NOT NULL condition exists to prevent extra sessions by the same user for the same date. TBH in this situation even if the NOT NULL condition is removed I still get a (empty) row returned. I think there is something I'm missing with Nulls and aggregate functions.

but it doesn't work. I've also seen where I could use an exception but that seems like a convoluted fix.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Further clarification as requested.

My table has four columns user, date, state, and verNumber

user and date are identifier columns ( not officially a PK but you can look at them that way).

state indicates if session was completed or not
verNumber indicates the the number of times that a session for that date was completed and can be null if no session for that date was completed.

I have a variable sessionNumber that I would like to assign either the MAX(VerNumber) available for that date or null when the date is unavailable or the value in VerNumber is null.

sample rows in Table_A

```
USER    | DATE       | STATE | VERNUMBER
'AName' | 2012-06-25 | 'YES' | 1
'CName' | 2012-06-25 | 'YES' | 2
'BName' | 2012-06-26 | 'NO'  | --NULL
```

so for date 06-25 I would expect 2 to be the value 
and for 06-26 I would expect null.

Comment: Trying to understand this clearly is difficult - can you explain it a bit better? You say you want to select the max version number or 'NULL' into a variable - but in your query you seem to explicity remove any NULL rows by doing VerNumber IS NOT NULL. What exactly are you trying to get for your output? Can you provide some more background and maybe expected output? Also look at the specification for NVL - it seems you are using it incorrectly: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php

Comment: Your question still isn't very clear. You say that you want to select `null into a sessionNumber`, and you get `one row when the col is null`. Sounds like what you want, so exactly is the desired result?

Comment: Initialize the variable to NULL before the SELECT statement.  The select statement is returning no rows for NULL, so the variable is not being set.

Comment: Yeah doesn't that make the variable NULL anyway? Which is what was required? **I want to select either the max version number or null into a sessionNumber variable for use in a C# program** - then again this is Oracle :D does Oracle not have defaults of 'NULL' for new variables? I'm usually using MSSQL

Comment: Allow me a few minutes and I will try to clear up the question but fundamentally I want my variable to be null unless there is an actual value that can assigned to it. What I'm getting now is an empty row, I want no rows to return at all.

Comment: So it looks like you need to do an ORDER BY and forget max, just use TOP 1 (or the Oracle equiv), since a MAX aggregate eliminates NULLs (in MSSQL - not sure about Oracle), I've dropped a SQL Fiddle in an answer using Oracle 11g R2 - my first foray into Oracle, does this get you any closer? Mess about with that - I've added 'SessionID' to the table, but you might be able to get away with using a CASE - how many is the maximum sessions do you expect to see for each date? I have an idea which may work

Comment: I think I've done it - by cheating a bit, using an alpha (or you could use a large numeric value) and a CASE to get the NULL to sort to the top. Then you can group by and still get the max. You need to subquery to convert the placeholder back to a NULL though - check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this close to what you want?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca465/1

Barking up wrong tree?

Edit: forget that last one

...does this look right to you!!?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44e50/21

I'm thinking maybe you want a single entry for each date though with the session which was last (no matter the user) - either way this gives you some hints

Edit: Here's that query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4163d/1

Which I think mirrors your output!

For everyones benefit (and in case SQL fiddle ever explodes!), the final query I did was:

```
SELECT Table_A.* FROM 
(
    SELECT
        SessionDate, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN VerNumber IS NULL THEN 'A' ELSE VerNumber END) as Ver
    FROM Table_A
    GROUP BY SessionDate
) TD
INNER JOIN Table_A 
ON NVL(Table_A.VerNumber, 'A') = TD.Ver 
AND Table_A.SessionDate = TD.SessionDate
```

So basically just used a CASE to get the MAX of an expression on the VerNumber column but use an alpha character to ensure that the NULLs in that column were selected by the MAX. The outer query joins to the inner on an expression using NVL() which allows the NULL to be joined to the 'A' in the inner query. Not sure if collation would cause issues here (does collation ever change the sort order of alpha vs numeric??)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through various examples for me. This was essentially a recreation of what I needed although I worked out the solution to my problem by reconfiguring other elements of the overall PL/SQL and creating an if situation.ALsp thanks for fiddle link I'll use it next time thanks for

Comment: No probs, it's a really good site that SqlFiddle :) - only just realised it did other DBs

Comment: @Charleh: Providing SQL Fiddle examples is an excellent way to help, but in my opinion your answer should still be available here at StackOverflow. Would be great if you could edit your answer again, providing that query and the link to the final fiddle here.

Comment: Hi Peter, I've added the query to the answer with a description, I'll make sure I do this in future in case SQL Fiddle is inaccessible or just literally explodes in a giant query filled mushroom cloud

Answer (score 1):

If you use an aggregate function alone in a select you'll always get a row. If you want no rows returned, you need to add another column and use GROUP BY and filter on that other column, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT VerNumber, MAX (VerNumber) 
  INTO sessionNumber 
  FROM Table_A 
 WHERE sessionDate = -- some date 
   AND VerNumber IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY VerNumber;
```

I don't know how your data is structured, so this may not be the exact solution. I'm also a bit confused, like the other who have commented, on exactly what you're trying to do.

Bear in mind, however, that if you do this you WILL need an exception handler, because you'll get a NO DATA FOUND exception.

Comment: Yes Somewhere in the mess above that is my questionm I mentioned that I was looking at an exception and this seems to be the only proper method to use. I'll work on this and try and post and update later.